# discord.py app command choice depending on user id

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to make a slash command with discord.py which has list of choices that depend on the calling user.

So let's say this is the example code:

```
@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.describe(fruits='fruits to choose from')
@app_commands.choices(fruits=[
    Choice(name='apple', value=1),
    Choice(name='banana', value=2),
    Choice(name='cherry', value=3),
])
async def fruit(interaction: discord.Interaction, fruits: Choice[int]):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your favourite fruit is {fruits.name}.')
```

I need these inputs (apple, banana, cherry) to be different depending on which user calls it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the choices defined for a command, as this information is synchronized with Discord when the command is defined. They were modeled to be constant. If you need a customizable input, but still have text suggestions, use [autocomplete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.autocomplete).